# Can sign convention be changed in lcapy

Tags: current

The question is in the header, here is the clarification. I have a circuit with netlist

V1  1   0   5;

R2  1   0   10;

and with the following schematic

[image]

and I solve it in lcapy. I get the branch currents \$i_{V_1}=0.5\$ and \$i_{R_2}=0.5\$. This is in accordance with lcapy documentation [lcapy doc](https://lcapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) -- if I understand it correctly) :

\$i_{V_1}=0.5\$ flows OUT of \$V_1\$ positive node 1, \$i_{R_2}\$ flows INTO the \$R_2\$ positive node 1. So at node 1 we have \$i_{V_1}+i_{R_2}=0\$, in accordance with KCL.

However, I find it confusing that inside source \$V_1\$ the current flows from negative node 0 to positive node 1. So here it is again:

QUESTION: Can I setup lcapy so that in voltage source \$V\$ with positive node \$x\$ and negative node \$y\$, the positive direction for current \$i_V\$ is from \$x\$ to \$y\$? And the same for current sources.

PS: This is not a question about DRAWING the circuit (which would be a circutikz question, and I think know the answer to that), It is about the actual computations performed by lcapy.

Comment: `voltage source V with positive node x and negative node y, the positive direction for current iV is from x to y? And the same for current sources.` Well, isn't *"from `x` through load to `y`, then through battery back to `x`"* the same thing with *"from `y` through battery to `x` then through the load back to `y`"* ?

Answer (score 0):

Despite you find it confusing, that inside source V1 the current flows from negative node 0 to positive node 1, it is actually how the current flows (e.g. inside a battery).

Current always flows in loops, so if it flows from + to - through the resistor, it must flow from - to + inside the voltage source. Else it would not form a loop.

Comment: @Kilic (and Wyss): I see and understand what you are saying. But when I defined the netlist (to use with lcapy or some other solver) I defined the \$V_1\$  branch as "1 0", i.e., the starting node is 1; so I would like the reference current direction to also be from 1 to 0 (yes, this would result in a negative current). At any rate, the question was specific:  _can I globally change the   lcapy convention_ ?

Comment: I understand your question and it is 100% legitimate to ask it. What I don't understand is why you would want this "inverse" lcapy convention. It is a agreed convention that current always flows from plus to minus outside a voltage source (because the negatively charged electrons flow in the other direction).

Comment: It started from using SPICE (actually SPICE-like) netlists. In the ones I have used  the positive orientation of botrh currents and voltages is from first-listed to last-listed node, same for sources, resistors and all other components.  Also, by this convention, every component with positive v*i product consumes power. So a voltage source, which provides power must have negative v*i; so the through-current  must be negative (i.e., flowing from negative to positive node inside the source).